# Moving a custom configuration group to a separate file

Tags: .net, handler, custom-configuration

I've recently wrote a rather large custom configuration group. I'm curious if it is possible to move this configuration to a separate file via the following:

```
<configuration>
    <configSections>
        <sectionGroup name="MyCustomGroup">
            <section name="MyCustomSection"/>
        </sectionGroup>
    </configSections>
    <MyCustomGroup file="alt.config" />
</configuration>
```

This is something similar to what you can do with the file attribute for appSettings. I realize there is most likely a need to create a ConfigurationPropertyAttribute for my custom section handler, however I've been unsuccessful in finding any example or direction in this regard.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

As far as I know, you *cannot* externalize an entire SectionGroup (i.e. `MyCustomGroup`) using the `configSource` attribute, but you have to handle this on the Section level (i.e. `MyCustomSection`)

```
<configuration>
    <configSections>
        <sectionGroup name="MyCustomGroup">
                <section name="MyCustomSection"/>
        </sectionGroup>
    </configSections>
    <MyCustomGroup>    
       <MyCustomSection configSource="externalfile.config" />
    </MyCustomGroup>
</configuration>
```

The external file `externalfile.config` would then contain your actual config settings, starting directly with your own custom section tag (no leading `<?xml....?>` or `<configuration>` or anything needed):

```
<MyCustomSection>
    ... your settings here......
</MyCustomSection>
```

Marc

Comment: You are correct. Section groups cannot be externalized as a whole, but its sections can.

Comment: @marc_s - great, I didn't realise this was such an old question. I was just googling and found this as the top result!

Comment: Exactly what I've needed.