# Custom ConfigurationSection to external .config

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-config

I know there is an easy way to move any "standard" config section to external file  i.e.

```
<appSettings file="myFile.config">
```

but what about a custom ConfigurationSection?

```
<configSections>
    <section name="someName" type="Namespace.SomeNameConfiguration" requirePermission="false" />
</configSections>

....

<someName>
  < bla bla bla ......
</someName>
```

Is there any similar way?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Moving a custom configuration group to a separate file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1562679/moving-a-custom-configuration-group-to-a-separate-file)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can use

`<somename configSource="myfile.config"/>`

However unlike `appSettings file=...`, you must put the entire section in the external file: there is no merging.