# Avoid giving server connection string in web.config

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, web

I am building a website using asp.net MVC. I have two connection strings in the web.config, one for local db and one for the server db. I am testing my work on local and then put it on the server. the server connection string (`user name and password`) is also in the web.config. Tomorrow when I sell the product, I want to make sure I don't give this web.config to the clients. but It can happen by mistake. How can I prevent this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My suggestion would be to use one of two methods:

A [ConnectionStrings.config](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5713147/custom-configurationsection-to-external-config) or a [Web.Config transform](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd465326(v=vs.110).aspx). As usual there are pros and cons for both.

**Using a separate config file for connection strings**

- Each developer can have a local copy of their connection strings
- ConnectionStrings can be marked to ignore and never committed to source control

However
 - Requires each client/developer to be individually managed

**Web.config transforms**

- Each connection string/build configuration can be source controlled
- Requires publish of application rather than just a build

However

- Can become difficult to maintain with large numbers of transforms.

Personally I prefer having a ConnectionStrings.config - I don't like having production credentials in source control. It also has the nice side effect of giving a build error if you've forgotten it so you can't leave them out by mistake.

Answer (score 2):

Don't use user name and password in the connection string, but use integrated security.

Instead of this.

```
User ID=****; Password=****;
```

Use this.

```
Integrated Security=true;
```

And make sure your logon user has access to the local database. And the IIS server has access to the server database.

See [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa984236%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) for configuring IIS to be able to access SQL Server.

Comment: Assuming you have access to IIS users this is a nice solution (that'll depend on the hosting the OP is using). Even better if you can name the databases the same!

Comment: @Liath, if the web server and web database on the same machine, it would be more easier just with `Data Source=.; Initial Catalog=DatabaseName; Integrated Security = true;` and we don't need to change it when deploying on server.