# How to call app.config from c# code when using 2 config files

Tags: c#, configuration, web-config, app-config

I have 2 config files in my application. When getting values from Web.config, I am using the below in c# and I get the values. But I am not sure how I can get some of the values from app.cofig.

```
ConfigurationManager.AppSettings[xsdSchema]
```

Appreciate the help.

Comment: I think that it is impossible. However why do you need to use 2 config files?

Comment: I was reading somewhere to use web.config for just IIS settings. And an other config file for all other setting like connection strings, app settings, etc for better programming methods. Isn't that true ??

Comment: I've never heard that.  You should just use the web.config for all your config settings

Answer (score 1, accepted):

App.config file is used in desktop/console applications. Web applications use web.config file. So you cannot use both in the same project.

However you can extract a web.config section into a [separate file](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1562727/4172979).